Raspberry Pico, MAX7819, Micropython based Spectrum Visualizer
I'm trying to build a spectrum visualizer for frequencies ranging 20-20000 Hz. I'm aware commercial products exist, but I'm doing it for the learning experience.
Each column of the MAX7819 module will correspond to a frequency: 30, 60, 125, 250, 375, 500, 750, 1000, 1500, 2000, 3000, 4000, 6000, 8000, 12000, 16000, 20000.
The problem:
Let's say we have an input sine wave of 1000 Hz and amplitude of 2.5v. The normalized value for the 1000 hz column should be 8 (LED dots) and zero for the other frequencies. However this is not the case
EDIT: Following @nekomatic advice got rid of the analog reading and MAX7819 code, replaced with a simulation. However the results are still the same
EDIT: With ChatGPT modifications (see last edit) the code started working for frequencies above 5000. However, the frequencies below 1000 Hz are filled with random values or empty.
import math
import time
from machine import Pin, ADC

# Constants
ADC_RESOLUTION = 65535
VOLTAGE_REF = 3.3
PEAK_VOLTAGE = 2.5
FREQUENCY = 375  # 1000 Hz
SAMPLES = 256
SAMPLING_RATE = 48000  # Total number of samples per second
MAXIMUM_EXPECTED_INTENSITY = 128

# Frequencies to analyze
TARGET_FREQUENCIES = [30, 60, 125, 250, 375, 500, 750, 1000, 1500, 2000, 3000, 4000, 6000, 8000, 12000, 16000, 20000]


# Function to generate simulated sine wave samples
def generate_sine_wave(frequency, samples, sampling_rate):
    audio_samples = []
    for n in range(samples):
        t = n / sampling_rate
        sine_value = 0.5 * math.sin(2 * math.pi * frequency * t)
        audio_samples.append(sine_value)
        time.sleep_us(int(1e6 / sampling_rate))  # Microsecond delay
    return audio_samples

# Custom FFT implementation
def fft(x):
    N = len(x)
    if N <= 1:
        return x
    even = fft(x[0::2])
    odd = fft(x[1::2])
    T = [complex(math.cos(-2 * math.pi * k / N), math.sin(-2 * math.pi * k / N)) * odd[k] for k in range(N // 2)]
    return [even[k] + T[k] for k in range(N // 2)] + [even[k] - T[k] for k in range(N // 2)]

# Perform FFT and get the intensity of target frequencies
def analyze_frequencies(audio_samples, sampling_rate, target_frequencies):
    fft_result = fft(audio_samples)
    magnitudes = [abs(x) for x in fft_result]
    freq_resolution = sampling_rate / len(audio_samples)

    intensities = {}
    for freq in target_frequencies:
        index = int(freq / freq_resolution)
        if index < len(magnitudes):
            intensities[freq] = magnitudes[index]
        else:
            intensities[freq] = 0  # If the frequency is out of the range
    
    return intensities

# Normalize samples for FFT
def normalize_samples(samples):
    min_sample = min(samples)
    max_sample = max(samples)
    normalized = [(sample - min_sample) / (max_sample - min_sample) * 2 - 1 for sample in samples]
    return normalized

# Normalize intensity to range 0-8 where 0 is 0 and max_intensity is 100
def normalize_intensity(intensity):
    return (intensity / MAXIMUM_EXPECTED_INTENSITY) * 8

# Example usage
audio_samples = generate_sine_wave(FREQUENCY, SAMPLES, SAMPLING_RATE)
normalized_samples = normalize_samples(audio_samples)

print(f"INPUT FREQUENCY: {FREQUENCY}")
print(f"SAMPLES: {SAMPLES}")
print(f"SAMPLING_RATE: {SAMPLING_RATE}")
print(f"\n")

intensities = analyze_frequencies(normalized_samples, SAMPLING_RATE, TARGET_FREQUENCIES)

# Print the intensities for the target frequencies
for freq in TARGET_FREQUENCIES:
    intensity = intensities[freq]
    normalized_intensity = normalize_intensity(intensity)
    print(f"Frequency {freq} Hz: Intensity {intensity}, Normalized Intensity {normalized_intensity:.2f}")

Results:
PASSED
    
    INPUT FREQUENCY: 375
    SAMPLES: 256
    SAMPLING_RATE: 48000
    
    
    Frequency 30 Hz: Intensity 8.34465e-07, Normalized Intensity 0.00
    Frequency 60 Hz: Intensity 8.34465e-07, Normalized Intensity 0.00
    Frequency 125 Hz: Intensity 8.34465e-07, Normalized Intensity 0.00
    Frequency 250 Hz: Intensity 5.74203e-06, Normalized Intensity 0.00
    Frequency 375 Hz: Intensity 128.0, Normalized Intensity 8.00
    Frequency 500 Hz: Intensity 128.0, Normalized Intensity 8.00
    Frequency 750 Hz: Intensity 8.191969e-06, Normalized Intensity 0.00
    Frequency 1000 Hz: Intensity 3.547676e-06, Normalized Intensity 0.00
    Frequency 1500 Hz: Intensity 4.489005e-06, Normalized Intensity 0.00
    Frequency 2000 Hz: Intensity 3.17708e-06, Normalized Intensity 0.00
    Frequency 3000 Hz: Intensity 2.353535e-06, Normalized Intensity 0.00
    Frequency 4000 Hz: Intensity 1.842429e-06, Normalized Intensity 0.00
    Frequency 6000 Hz: Intensity 1.397866e-06, Normalized Intensity 0.00
    Frequency 8000 Hz: Intensity 8.17483e-07, Normalized Intensity 0.00
    Frequency 12000 Hz: Intensity 4.792896e-06, Normalized Intensity 0.00
    Frequency 16000 Hz: Intensity 1.127158e-06, Normalized Intensity 0.00
    Frequency 20000 Hz: Intensity 4.517486e-06, Normalized Intensity 0.00

FAILED

INPUT FREQUENCY: 20000
SAMPLES: 256
SAMPLING_RATE: 48000


Frequency 30 Hz: Intensity 0.6341498, Normalized Intensity 0.04
Frequency 60 Hz: Intensity 0.6341498, Normalized Intensity 0.04
Frequency 125 Hz: Intensity 0.6341498, Normalized Intensity 0.04
Frequency 250 Hz: Intensity 0.6341088, Normalized Intensity 0.04
Frequency 375 Hz: Intensity 0.6341305, Normalized Intensity 0.04
Frequency 500 Hz: Intensity 0.6341305, Normalized Intensity 0.04
Frequency 750 Hz: Intensity 0.6348932, Normalized Intensity 0.04
Frequency 1000 Hz: Intensity 0.6354204, Normalized Intensity 0.04
Frequency 1500 Hz: Intensity 0.6377634, Normalized Intensity 0.04
Frequency 2000 Hz: Intensity 0.6398275, Normalized Intensity 0.04
Frequency 3000 Hz: Intensity 0.649468, Normalized Intensity 0.04
Frequency 4000 Hz: Intensity 0.6605797, Normalized Intensity 0.04
Frequency 6000 Hz: Intensity 0.6991645, Normalized Intensity 0.04
Frequency 8000 Hz: Intensity 0.7543576, Normalized Intensity 0.05
Frequency 12000 Hz: Intensity 1.000046, Normalized Intensity 0.06
Frequency 16000 Hz: Intensity 1.757033, Normalized Intensity 0.11
Frequency 20000 Hz: Intensity 52.93431, Normalized Intensity 3.31


FAILED

INPUT FREQUENCY: 30
SAMPLES: 256
SAMPLING_RATE: 48000


Frequency 30 Hz: Intensity 23.68655, Normalized Intensity 1.48
Frequency 60 Hz: Intensity 23.68655, Normalized Intensity 1.48
Frequency 125 Hz: Intensity 23.68655, Normalized Intensity 1.48
Frequency 250 Hz: Intensity 84.25122, Normalized Intensity 5.27
Frequency 375 Hz: Intensity 41.19667, Normalized Intensity 2.57
Frequency 500 Hz: Intensity 41.19667, Normalized Intensity 2.57
Frequency 750 Hz: Intensity 20.49077, Normalized Intensity 1.28
Frequency 1000 Hz: Intensity 16.38545, Normalized Intensity 1.02
Frequency 1500 Hz: Intensity 10.24358, Normalized Intensity 0.64
Frequency 2000 Hz: Intensity 8.200925, Normalized Intensity 0.51
Frequency 3000 Hz: Intensity 5.1448, Normalized Intensity 0.32
Frequency 4000 Hz: Intensity 3.937964, Normalized Intensity 0.25
Frequency 6000 Hz: Intensity 2.622571, Normalized Intensity 0.16
Frequency 8000 Hz: Intensity 2.036124, Normalized Intensity 0.13
Frequency 12000 Hz: Intensity 1.419293, Normalized Intensity 0.09
Frequency 16000 Hz: Intensity 1.161598, Normalized Intensity 0.07
Frequency 20000 Hz: Intensity 1.041309, Normalized Intensity 0.07

EDIT:
ChatGPT implemented a Kaiser window function, increased sampling to 256, and a way to see the bins. Frequencies 30 and 60 did not have any bins, so removed them.
import math
import time

# Constants
FREQUENCY =  300
SAMPLES = 256  # Increased number of samples
SAMPLING_RATE = 48000  # Total number of samples per second

# Frequencies to analyze
TARGET_FREQUENCIES = [125, 250, 375, 500, 750, 1000, 1500, 2000, 3000, 4000, 6000, 8000, 12000, 16000, 20000]

# Maximum expected intensity
MAXIMUM_EXPECTED_INTENSITY = 100

# Function to generate simulated sine wave samples
def generate_sine_wave(frequency, samples, sampling_rate):
    audio_samples = []
    for n in range(samples):
        t = n / sampling_rate
        sine_value = 0.5 * math.sin(2 * math.pi * frequency * t)
        audio_samples.append(sine_value)
        time.sleep_us(int(1e6 / sampling_rate))  # Microsecond delay
    return audio_samples

# Custom FFT implementation
def fft(x):
    N = len(x)
    if N <= 1:
        return x
    even = fft(x[0::2])
    odd = fft(x[1::2])
    T = [complex(math.cos(-2 * math.pi * k / N), math.sin(-2 * math.pi * k / N)) * odd[k] for k in range(N // 2)]
    return [even[k] + T[k] for k in range(N // 2)] + [even[k] - T[k] for k in range(N // 2)]

# Perform FFT and get the intensity of target frequencies
def analyze_frequencies(audio_samples, sampling_rate, target_frequencies):
    fft_result = fft(audio_samples)
    magnitudes = [abs(x) for x in fft_result]
    freq_resolution = sampling_rate / len(audio_samples)

    intensities = {}
    for freq in target_frequencies:
        index = int(freq / freq_resolution)
        if index < len(magnitudes):
            intensities[freq] = magnitudes[index]
        else:
            intensities[freq] = 0  # If the frequency is out of the range
    
    return intensities

# Normalize samples for FFT
def normalize_samples(samples):
    min_sample = min(samples)
    max_sample = max(samples)
    normalized = [(sample - min_sample) / (max_sample - min_sample) * 2 - 1 for sample in samples]
    return normalized

# Normalize intensity to range 0-8 where 0 is 0 and max_intensity is 100
def normalize_intensity(intensity):
    return (intensity / MAXIMUM_EXPECTED_INTENSITY) * 8 if intensity < MAXIMUM_EXPECTED_INTENSITY else 8

# Hamming window function UNUSED
def hamming_window(samples):
    windowed_samples = []
    for n in range(len(samples)):
        window_value = 0.54 - 0.46 * math.cos(2 * math.pi * n / (len(samples) - 1))
        windowed_samples.append(samples[n] * window_value)
    return windowed_samples

# Kaiser window function
def kaiser_window(samples, beta=10):
    windowed_samples = []
    for n in range(len(samples)):
        arg = 1 - ((n - (len(samples) - 1) / 2) / ((len(samples) - 1) / 2)) ** 2
        bessel = math.sqrt(math.pi) * math.e ** (1 / beta) / (2 * beta)
        window_value = bessel * math.sqrt(arg)
        windowed_samples.append(samples[n] * window_value)
    return windowed_samples

def print_bins():
    
    #Bin frequency= Sampling rate​/Number of samples
    #Each bin will correspond to a frequency range determined by this formula.
    #For example, if you have 256 samples and a sampling rate of 48000 Hz, each frequency bin will cover:
    #48000256≈187.5 Hz25648000​≈187.5 Hz

    # Calculate frequency range per bin
    bin_frequency = SAMPLING_RATE / SAMPLES

    # Calculate bin indices for target frequencies
    bin_indices = [round(freq / bin_frequency) for freq in TARGET_FREQUENCIES]

    print("Bin indices for target frequencies:")
    for freq, index in zip(TARGET_FREQUENCIES, bin_indices):
        print(f"Frequency {freq} Hz: Bin index {index}")
    
    frequency_resolution = SAMPLING_RATE / SAMPLES

    # Original target frequencies below 500 Hz
    original_frequencies_below_500 = [30, 60, 125, 250, 375]

    # Adjust frequencies to align with frequency resolution
    adjusted_frequencies_below_500 = [
        int(frequency_resolution * round(freq / frequency_resolution)) 
        for freq in original_frequencies_below_500
        ]

    print("Adjusted Frequencies Below 500 Hz:", adjusted_frequencies_below_500)


    print(f"\n")
    
def print_intensities():
    # Print the intensities for the target frequencies
    for freq in TARGET_FREQUENCIES:
        intensity = intensities[freq]
        normalized_intensity = normalize_intensity(intensity)
        print(f"Frequency {freq} Hz: Intensity {intensity}, Normalized Intensity {normalized_intensity:.2f}")

# Main Loop

print(f"INPUT FREQUENCY: {FREQUENCY}")
print(f"SAMPLES: {SAMPLES}")
print(f"SAMPLING_RATE: {SAMPLING_RATE}")
print(f"\n")

print_bins()
audio_samples = generate_sine_wave(FREQUENCY, SAMPLES, SAMPLING_RATE)
windowed_samples = kaiser_window(audio_samples)
normalized_samples = normalize_samples(windowed_samples)
intensities = analyze_frequencies(normalized_samples, SAMPLING_RATE, TARGET_FREQUENCIES)
print_intensities()


You're doing two separate tasks here: 1) sampling the audio signal and 2) calculating the FFT. I would separate these out: test the FFT code using known input data, and inspect the sampled audio data before it goes into the FFT (for example you could save one set of samples to a file, or print the samples to the console and capture the printed data on your desktop machine, then load that into a spreadsheet and plot a graph of it). When you know where the problem is, edit your question to focus on that code.

Thank you nekomantic. Indeed, first step for debugging problematic code is to split the problem is smaller parts. Rookie mistake, updated the code accordingly
